# Advanced selector - Hide Parent

Tags: javascript, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<td>
 <a class="button" href="#">
  <input id="download">...</input>
 </a>
 <a class="button" href="#">
  <input id="downloadcsv">...</input>
 </a>
</td>
```

Using `CSS` I want to hide the `<a>` which contains an `input` with the `ID = downloadcsv`

Is there a parent option in CSS?

Edit: As current aswers indicate you cant hide a parent element based on the class of one of its childeren.

Is it possible to do this simply in Javascript, rather than using a framework like jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the `<a>` is the direct parent of the `downloadcsv`-input, you can just use

```
document.getElementById("downloadcsv").parentNode.style.display = "none"
```

Comment: This is the correct way to obtain the DOM node's parent using JS.

The reason why it's not possible with CSS is because current selectors allow you to target elements, children, siblings--but not parents.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with CSS (2). However, it is possible with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Fran's answer, the jQuery solution would be this:

```
$("a:has(#downloadcsv)").hide();
```

Otherwise, you'll need to put a class on the parent `<a>` indicating that it is the parent of `#downloadscv`.